# Can the Crank-Nicholson method be used to solve systems of stiff ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I know that this method can be used to solve PDEs. Can I use the same method to solve systems of stiff ODEs?

If this is the case could you provide a reference, either a paper or a text book, where this had been done.

Comment: Crank-Nicolson is just a name for using the trapezoidal rule on an ODE resulting from discretization of a certain type of PDE. So in the ODE context it would *just* be the trapezoidal rule...which as it happens is often not that great.

Comment: @ian what is the simplest stiff solver that you would recommend?

Comment: Unless your problem is huge, or you have some other really good reason to do this yourself, I'd just give ode23s a shot before trying anything else.

Comment: thanks @Ian, so Rosenbrock formula of order 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you try for the following equation $\frac{du}{dt} = -100*u(t)$  with $u(0) = 1$, the method will be:

$\frac{u_{n+1} - u_n}{h} = \frac{1}{2}*((-100*u_{n+1})+(-100*u_n))$

$\implies u_{n+1} = \frac{\frac{-2}{100}+h}{\frac{-2}{100}-h} * u_n$

This system converges like center difference method and able to find $u(t) = e^{-100t}$